# JPA cannot change column used in foreign key constraint

Tags: java, spring, database, jpa, relational-database

I have strange database structure where I have a pair of 2 foreign keys as primary key in 1 table. In another table I have 3 foreign keys and as a primary key and I struggle to make that as a JPA entity class.
The error I get is:  Cannot change column 'workstep_no': used in a foreign key constraint 'fk_order_has_workstep_workstep'

Here is the db Schema: [image: db schema]
Here are some of my entity classes
OrderHasWorkstep

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_has_workstep", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_order_idx", columnList = "order_order_no"),
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_workstep_idx", columnList = "workstep_workstep_no, workstep_article_article_no"),
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_machine_idx", columnList = "machine_machine_no")
})
public class OrderHasWorkstep {
    @EmbeddedId
    private OrderHasWorkstepId id;

    @MapsId("orderOrderNo")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_order_no", nullable = false)
    private Order orderOrderNo;

    @MapsId("id")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "workstep_workstep_no", referencedColumnName = "workstep_no", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "workstep_article_article_no", referencedColumnName = "article_article_no", nullable = false)
    })
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Workstep workstep;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "machine_machine_no")
    private Machine machineMachineNo;

    @Column(name = "planned_calendar_week", length = 7)
    private String plannedCalendarWeek;

    @Column(name = "starting_date", length = 7)
    private String startingDate;

    @Column(name = "ending_date", length = 7)
    private String endingDate;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private Integer status;
// getters and setters
```

OrderHasWorkstepId:

```
@Embeddable
public class OrderHasWorkstepId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -488175951625341581L;
    @Column(name = "order_order_no", nullable = false, length = 10)
    private String orderOrderNo;

    @Column(name = "workstep_workstep_no", nullable = false, length = 3)
    private String workstepWorkstepNo;

    @Column(name = "workstep_article_article_no", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String workstepArticleArticleNo;
//getters setters hashcode equals
```

Workstep:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "workstep", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_workstep_article_idx", columnList = "article_article_no")
})
public class Workstep {
    @EmbeddedId
    private WorkstepId id;

    @MapsId("articleArticleNo")
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "article_article_no", nullable = false)
    private Article articleArticleNo;

    @Lob
    @Column(name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name = "setup_time")
    private LocalTime setupTime;

    @Column(name = "run_time")
    private LocalTime runTime;

    @Column(name = "machine_group", length = 5)
    private String machineGroup;
//getters setters
```

WorkstepId

```
@Embeddable
public class WorkstepId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2987311413950947398L;
    @Column(name = "workstep_no", nullable = false, length = 3)
    private String workstepNo;

    @Column(name = "article_article_no", nullable = false, length = 45)
    private String articleArticleNo;
```

I tried to restructure the WorkstepIds to use entities not just strings but it still didnt work. I assume it could be something to do with the pair of columns as primary key taken into order_has_workstep

Comment: @MapsId("id") doesn't look at all right - the 'id' property is the full OrderHasWorkstepId embeddable, and you've already pointed the @MapsId("orderOrderNo") at it. Instead of bending your model backwards to use an embedded id, why not look at marking your relationships as IDs directly instead. Put the relationship's Id classes exactly as they are (so WorkstepId for the Workstep) in an IdClass.

Comment: You are correct. Your way makes more sense but I get the same error apparently if I change the property of spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update to none it works. But I am not sure if it actually fixes the problem or delays it for later.

Comment: Use drop and create instead. Not all  model and mapping changes will easily be 'updated' into an existing schema with data already in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try more simply:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_has_workstep", indexes = {
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_order_idx", columnList = "order_order_no"),
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_workstep_idx", columnList = "workstep_workstep_no, workstep_article_article_no"),
        @Index(name = "fk_order_has_workstep_machine_idx", columnList = "machine_machine_no")
})
@IdClass(OrderHasWorkstepId.class)
public class OrderHasWorkstep {

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_order_no", nullable = false)
    private Order orderOrderNo;

    @Id
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "workstep_workstep_no", referencedColumnName = "workstep_no", nullable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "workstep_article_article_no", referencedColumnName = "article_article_no", nullable = false)
    })
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Workstep workstep;
  ..
}


public class OrderHasWorkstepId implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -488175951625341581L;

    private String orderOrderNo;
    private WorkstepId workstep;
    ..
}
```

With JPA derived IDs, the referenced entity's ID must be used as is in the ID class, and named the same as the ID property.

Comment: It worked and it makes more sense that way. Auto-generated entities are double edged sword I guess you dont have to take them for granted.  It extracted only the object attributes in OrderHasWorkstepId but perhaps it caused conflict with their instances in OrderHasWorkstep. Thank you.